# Не получается изменить html илемент после добавления его же .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма.

```
form = $('#form_id');
```

запускается таймер, и в форму вставляется отсчет

```
form.find('.wrapper').html('<div class="timer">таймер</div>');
```

После завершения таймера (на самом деле она запускается каждую секунду и проверяет не истекло ли время) запускается функция с `clearInterval` и моими дополнительными заданиями (поменять текст, включить кнопку и т.п.) и в списке есть

```
form.find('.wrapper').html('<div class="timer">другой текст</div>');
```

Но последняя команда не срабатывает. Более того, что бы я не пытался сделать с `div.timer` - ничего не выходит.

Код таймера, который нашел на просторах интернета, не знаю насколько оптимален, но визуально мне подошел, убрал оттуда дни и часы (мне нужен был отсчет 3х минут).

Форма обрабатывается при ajax'ом. Приходит удачный ответ от сервера и выполняются

```
initializeTimer();
```

Код таймера с моими изменениями (время установлено 5 сек, чтобы долго не ждать)

```
function initializeTimer() {
        var seconds = 5000 / 1000; // определяем количество секунд до истечения таймера
        if (seconds > 0) { 
            var minutes = seconds/60; // определяем количество минут до истечения таймера
            var hours = minutes/60; // определяем количество часов до истечения таймера
            minutes = (hours - Math.floor(hours)) * 60; // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе
            hours = Math.floor(hours); // целое количество часов до истечения таймера
            seconds = Math.floor((minutes - Math.floor(minutes)) * 60); // подсчитываем кол-во оставшихся секунд в текущей минуте
            minutes = Math.floor(minutes); // округляем до целого кол-во оставшихся минут в текущем часе

            setTimePage(minutes,seconds); // выставляем начальные значения таймера

            function secOut() {
              if (seconds == 0) { // если секунду закончились то
                  if (minutes == 0) { // если минуты закончились то
                      if (hours == 0) { // если часы закончились то
                          showMessage(timerId); // выводим сообщение об окончании отсчета
                      }
                      else {
                          hours--; // уменьшаем кол-во часов
                          minutes = 59; // обновляем минуты 
                          seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
                      }
                  }
                  else {
                      minutes--; // уменьшаем кол-во минут
                      seconds = 59; // обновляем секунды
                  }
              }
              else {
                  seconds--; // уменьшаем кол-во секунд
              }
              setTimePage(minutes,seconds); // обновляем значения таймера на странице
            }
            timerId = setInterval(secOut, 1000) // устанавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
        }
        else {
            alert("Установленная дата уже прошла");
        }
    }

    function setTimePage(m,s) { // функция выставления таймера на странице
        //var element = document.getElementById("timer"); // находим элемент с id = timer
        //element.innerHTML = "Минуты:"+m+"<br>Секунды:"+s; // выставляем новые значения таймеру на странице
        auth_form.find('.response').html('<div id="logmodal_timer">Вам отправлен sms-пароль.<br>'+m+' мин. '+s+' сек.</div>');
    }

    function showMessage(timerId) { // функция, вызываемая по истечении времени

        auth_form.find('#code').hide().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        auth_form.find('input[type="submit"]').val('Получить новый sms-пароль');
        clearInterval(timerId); // останавливаем вызов функции через каждую секунду
        auth_form.find('.response').html('<div id="logmodal_timer">Убираем таймер, показываем другой текст</div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setTimePage` в `secOut` вызывается, даже если время закончилось:

```
showMessage(timerId); 
return; // добавить эту строчку
```

Comment: Спасибо, хотя я пока ковырялся, другой таймер нашел, с более лаконичным кодом и без этого каскада `if else`. Вопрос ещё - как-то можно принудительно очищать таймер с его остановкой (clearInterval), но из другой функции какой-то? К примеру клик по какому-то объекту. Вопрос касательно всех таймеров и этого в частности. У меня получилось только через объявление глобальной переменной `var my_timer = false;` и уже в самой ф-ии таймера я устанавливал `my_timer = setInterval...` а в другой (внешней ф-ии) сбрасывал при помощи той же глобальной переменной. Но читал, что стоит избегать глобальных ф-ий?

Comment: @Aaron Вы имеете в виду "глобальных переменных". Да, их лучше не использовать. Поэтому Вы можете весь Ваш код завернуть в IIFE: `(function(){...})();`.

Comment: глобальные - это те, которые просто объявляются вне функции, так ведь? Я об этом. А в чём смысл IIFE в данной ситуации? Судя по гуглу  это конструкция, позволяющая вызвать функцию сразу же в месте ее определения.